# How to check a connection to MySQL db is not dead, and avoid unnecessarily (close and) re-create connection?

Tags: mysql, connection, monitoring

How to check a connection to MySQL db is not dead, and avoid unnecessarily (close and) re-create connection?  Say, I am creating and using the connection in a Bash script.

#### Edit

By "dead" i mean, perhaps the last time when a created connection was used is 1 hr ago, and on the server side, perhaps it does something to kill off inactive connections in some way.

Comment: What do you mean by "dead"? Can you show the code?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-pconnect.php ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to check is to try to use it.

You could pre-emptively execute a basic command like `SELECT 1` before executing your real command.